# I want to store the edited spinner value in the database

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

my coding is working well .But I want to store the edited spinner value in the database how it be done.here is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class tooo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Spinner localSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.color_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.color_array, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_item_style);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        localSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);    
    }
}
```

my simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add follwoing after setting the adapter in your code

```
localSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int position, long id) 
        {
            String text = localSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //The above text variable has the selected value of spinner
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parentView) 
        {
        }
    });
```

Why didnt you edited question in your last post rather than creating a new post